# Is this JAVA MySQL JDBC Google App Engine connection string valid?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc

Please tell me if the connection string inside this method is a valid connection string:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                  "jdbc:google:mysql://cloud-2280:mysql/account"
                  , "root"
                  , "");
```

- appID: cloud-2280
- instanceID: mysql
- DBname: account
- password: mypassword

This is the exception:

> com.conversedynamics.NewServlet doPost: null
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the
>   server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets
>   from the server. at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:668) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1078) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2417) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2450)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2235)
>   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:818) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:46) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:46) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver$JdbcWrapper.getInstance(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:282)
>   at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.connect(GoogleNonRegisteringDriver.java:252)
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233) at
>   com.conversedynamics.NewServlet.doPost(NewServlet.java:90) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
>   at
>   com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.io.EOFException: Can not read response from server. Expected to
>   read 4 bytes, read 0 bytes before connection was unexpectedly lost. at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:3039) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:592)

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @Simze: First of all, thanks for responding. I get the dreaded CommunicationsException: Communications link failure. It's a long story. I tried many things for about a week now. I just want to verify that the connection string is valid, because everything else seems to be OK!

Comment: If you get some exception please post the full stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/), your jdbc url looks valid.

Good look.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So the problem is elsewhere then.

Answer (score 0):

Were you ever able to overcome this? Whenever I've seen this, it's often related to security configurations between the client and the mySQL server.

"Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server."

Try appending "?verifyServerCertificate=false;useSSL=false" to your url. The server may be expecting more security than you're specifying in your connection string. These commands override these, making the connection less secure. But if you connect, you know where you need to focus your attention. Of course, you would not want to be running with security disabled. But it is a way to understand where your problem is.